# Probability problem involving waiting time at pharmacy

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm working on the following problem:

[image]

---

The case of Safeway is very easy as the answer is simply the mean of $f_T$, namely $1$ minute. However, I'm having problems solving this problem for Target. I feel like this looks like a problem that would lend itself to CDFs, but I can't quite see how to use them. Other methods don't see to be applicable since there are two cashiers competing for the customer, so that makes the problem much more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

**Outline:** For Safeway, it is straightforward, but recall that it is waiting time **plus** serving time. By the memorylessness of the exponential, the mean waiting time is $1$. Add to this the mean serving time.

For Target, the mean waiting time is different. Let $U$ be the time until the first cashier finishes, and $V$ the waiting time until the second does. Then your waiting time is $\min(U,V)$. For the distribution of $W$, note that $W\gt w$ precisely if $U\gt w$ **and** $V\gt w$. The probability of this is $(e^{-w})^2$. Now you can find the distribution of $W$, and hence its expectation.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

For waiting time at Target it comes to finding the expectation of $\min\left\{ T_{1},T_{2}\right\} $
where $T_{1}$ and $T_{2}$ are iid having exponential distribution
with parameter $1$.